# String class color in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I just tried out Sublime Text 3, and everything went well except one problem: I couldn't change the color of the `string` class. every other functions, types has its own color that can be changed, but no matter what the theme I'm using, the `string` class is always the foreground color. The same problem seems to happen to `namespace` as well. Is there any way I can change them? It's nothing serious or functionally implicated, I'm simply a little perfectionist.[image]

P.S. I've located the .tmlanguage file and have resolved the `namespace` problem with another code I copied from a c++ 11 package. If you could just tell me which code to add to the .tmlanguage file to make the `string` class work, it would be the best. Thank you
[image: The ideal scheme I hope for, with <code>string</code> and <code>cout</code> colored]

Comment: Sublime Text uses themes in Textmate format, see [here](http://manual.macromates.com/en/themes) on how to create/edit them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sublime, it is the **color scheme** ***`.tmTheme`*** file that is responsible for coloring elements of different scopes, which are defined by the **language definition** ***`.tmLanguage`*** file. Just about all strings are defined as part of the `string` scope, and many color schemes, including most of the ones included with Sublime, just have a single color for `string`. One issue I have with these color schemes is that they are generally based on a small handful of colors, and reuse them for many different scopes - Monokai and its derivatives are chief offenders of this crime, IMHO. If you want to change the color of the `string` scope, you'll need to find and edit the `.tmTheme` file associated with your color scheme.

In Sublime Text 3 this is most easily accomplished by installing @skuroda's [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin via Package Control. Once installed, open the Command Palette and type ***`prv`***, then choose **`PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`**. If you're wishing to modify one of the built-in themes, navigate down to `Color Schemes - Default`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click, then scroll through the list until you find the name of the color scheme you're using. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click on it, and an XML file will open. Search for `<string>string` (make sure you don't have regex search turned on) and you should find the section you're looking for. Edit the hex color code to something more palatable, save the file, and your views will automatically be updated.

BTW, if you're looking for a complex, hugely-multicolored color scheme with a color definition for just about any scope out there, I recommend checking out the [`Neon Color Scheme`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme), also available via Package Control. If you're curious, here's how your code snippet looks when using the full [C++11](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/C%2B%2B11) syntax definition:

[image: C++11 with Neon.tmTheme]

If you want, you can always modify it, or take pieces for your own work. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty detailed. And I did use the `PackageResourceViewer` to try edit both the `.tmtheme` file and the `.tmlanguage` file. However, the problem I'm still having (and it still exists in your scheme as well) is the keyword `string`, not the string itself. The same problem goes to the keyword `cout` and many others. I don't know how to attach pictures in comment, so I've attached another image in the main post to show what I really want (which is a screenshot I took from Xcode without any modifications).

Comment: @JupiterM - are you using the C++11 syntax definition? I'll take a look at it when I can and see if I can add support for the `string` and `cout` keywords. I'm not a C++ programmer, is there a list of keywords you'd like included?

Comment: There's no C++11 in sublime text 3, so I'm using the default C++ syntax. As for Xcode, I'm using the default, so I assume it's C++11 syntax. What I find has a problem in the scheme include `string` class, `namespace` class & its types, different stream functions, e.g. `cout`, `cin`, `ifstream`,etc. Thanks

Comment: @MattDMo - I just downloaded `Neon` and it looks like you still have not included the `string` class in your color scheme.

Comment: @nodebase I'm not quite sure what you mean - can you open an [issue](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-color-scheme/issues/new) so we can discuss it? Using the [`C++11`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/C%2B%2B11) syntax the above screenshot is still accurate. What `string` class did you mean?

Comment: @MattDMo: Their is a class in C++'s Standard Template Library called <string>. If you notice in the screen shot above, on line 7, the class name is not highlighted/colored. The original poster wants that class type "string" to be colored just as if it were a primitive type, like int, float, char, and so on. Do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try a different syntax highlighter, there are several packages for C-like languages available via [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/about)

Comment: this is an issue with the color scheme, not the syntax definition

Comment: I found one "Syntax manager", which does not have any readme on how to "manage" syntax... Do you have any specific recommendations?

Comment: @MattDMo I've tested some syntax definitions (e.g. C++11) without changing the colour scheme and it *did* change the colouring of the syntax!

Comment: @idleberg - yes, that's true, but at list for `string` it shouldn't change, regardless of the syntax being used.